# Why does pandas Round method explodes my data frame?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, rounding

I try to round all values in this [dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/adl22tvse2bicsq/dfna.pkl?dl=0). However, the pandas [round() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) explodes my dataframe by a factor 5! From 150 rows to 7518 rows.

It may be that there is something odd with the data in the dataframe, but then again, one would not expect a simple rounding function to do this.

Below, I replicate the error using 1) simulated data and 2) the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/adl22tvse2bicsq/dfna.pkl?dl=0) that leads to the said error.

This results in 150 rows, which is the correct number:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([150, 4]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df["cat"] = "MID"
df.loc[:399,["cat"]] = "LOW"
df.iloc[-400:,-1] = "HI"
df.cat.value_counts()
df.set_index("cat", inplace=True)
df.round(3)
```

Using the data from my dropbox folder, the round-function produces a whopping 7518 rows:

```
dfb = pd.read_pickle('dfna.pkl')
dfb.round(3)
```

This is strange. I solved it for now using this rather ugly line:

```
dfb = dfb.reset_index().round({'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 3, 'D': 3}).set_index('tricile')
```

However, this is not ideal, given that pandas' round method acts in mysterious ways and may affect future programs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is bug - `round` with duplicated `CategoricalIndex`, so created [pandas issue 21809](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21809) and [pandas issue 21810](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21810).

Similar solution like your is:

```
print (dfb.reset_index().round(3).set_index('tricile'))
```

Or remove `CategoricalIndex`:

```
dfb.index = dfb.index.astype(str)
print (dfb.round(3))
```

Comment: Git bug is duplicate of https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21810

Comment: I posted the one on GIT after jezrael's answer.